# How to append data value to dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to associate a data value with a div created dynamically, however I have not been able to get this to work. I've tried looking around online but can't seem to adapt any examples to fit my problem. If anyone could help I would be very appreciative. The error I'm getting says that:

> .data is not a function

If I try putting the `$` operator in front control just passes right through my block of code and nothing happens.

```
var container = $("#container");
('<div class="orb"></div>').data(num).appendTo(container);
```

Comment: missing `$`... `$('<div class="orb"></div>').data(num).appendTo(container);`

Comment: Try to put `$` in front of `('<div class="orb"></div>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well:

```js
var $container = $('#container');
$('<div class="orb"></div>').data('num', 123).appendTo($container);

console.log($('.orb').data('num'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

What is your problem?